# retrieving UITextField position on screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How can I retrieve the position of my UITextField??

I can create many UITextFields proprammly and then move them on screen. then in the following way (by tag), I detect fine the writing, but I also want the position (es: GRect 0,0,0,0).

```
for (UITextField *text in array2) {


int touchedtag = text.tag;

NSUInteger tagCount = touchedtag;
switch (tagCount) {
    case 1: 
        size = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", text.frame];


        object = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@", text.text, size];

        break;

 }
```

I tried this (using size) but it does not work. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of the textField should show in `textfield.frame`. But if you wan't to NSLog the frame you need to use `NSStringFromCGRect(textField.frame)`.